# Performance issues in simulation with python lists

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.x, simulation

I'm currently writing a simulation in python 3.4 (miniconda).
The entire simulation is quite fast but the measurement of some simulation data is bloody slow and takes about 35% of the entire simulation time. I hope I can increase the performance of the entire simulation if I could get rid of that bottleneck. I spend quite some time to figure out how to do that but unfortunately with little success. The function MeasureValues is called in every period of the simulation run.

If anybody has an idea how to improve the code, I would be really grateful.

Thank you guys.

```
def MeasureValues(self, CurrentPeriod):
    if CurrentPeriod > self.WarmUp:
        self.ValueOne[CurrentPeriod] = self.FixedValueOne if self.Futurevalue[CurrentPeriod + self.Reload] > 0 else 0
        self.ValueTwo[CurrentPeriod] = self.VarValueTwo * self.AmountValueTwo[CurrentPeriod]
        self.ValueThree[CurrentPeriod] = self.VarValueThree  * self.AmountValueThree[CurrentPeriod]
        self.SumOfValues[CurrentPeriod] = self.ValueOne[CurrentPeriod] + self.ValueTwo[CurrentPeriod] + self.ValueThree[CurrentPeriod]
        self.TotalSumOfValues += self.SumOfValues[CurrentPeriod]

        self.HelperSumValueFour += self.ValueFour[CurrentPeriod]
        self.HelperSumValueTwo += self.AmountValueTwo[CurrentPeriod]
        self.HelperSumValueFive += self.ValueFive[CurrentPeriod]

        self.RatioOne[CurrentPeriod] = (1 - (self.HelperSumValueFour / self.HelperSumValueFive )) if self.HelperSumValueFive > 0 else 1
        self.RatioTwo[CurrentPeriod] = (1 - (self.HelperSumValueTwo  / self.HelperSumValueFive )) if self.HelperSumValueFive > 0 else 1
```

Comment: If you have variables that are named `varOne`, `varTwo`, ... `varN`, that typically means you should have a list of `vars`. Also, Python conventions use `lowercase_separated` variable names, not titled `CamelCase`

Comment: That's just due to the simplification of the example :)

Comment: Alright. Well, I'm just seeing some simple math here. Where is the bottleneck?

Comment: The whole function is the bottleneck of my simulation. Everything else is really fast.

Comment: The function look quite simple, only math and some list (?) index-based access, so I don't see the problem there, If you can provide more informations: how did you estimate the function performances? Can you provide the complete code? Can you provide some number that quantify "bloody slow"?

Comment: I just measured the total time of each function I run within the simulation and this one which is just monitoring some values takes for a simulation of e.g. 3,000,000 periods 17 out of 54 seconds and is by far the slowest function. Normally this wouldn't be a problem but as I have to run hundreds of simulations, it adds up significantly. I also thought about writing that code in ctype (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). Do you think that would help?

Comment: ctypes is more suited for calling/wrapping existing C code, take a look at some possible alternatives in the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks basic enough that there aren't any obvious gaps for optimisation without substantial restructuring (which I don't know enough about your overall architecture to suggest).

Try installing [`cython`](http://cython.org/) - I believe nowadays you can install it with `pip install cython` - then use it to see if you can speed up your code any.

Comment: Either I did it wrong or it doesn't change anything. I installed cython, compiled my simulation skript and run it from a different python skript.

Comment: Is that the right way? I just did it as it is explained in the first example here http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments the function is quite simple, and with the provided code I don't see a way to optimize it directly.

You can try different approaches:

1. [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), this may works depending on your current codebase and external dependecies.
2. [Cython](http://cython.org/) as suggested by *holdenweb*, but you need to redefine a lot of stuff to be static-typed (using `cdef`) or nothing will change.
3. rewrite the function in C as a [Python extension](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html), this may take some time, especially if you have no experience in C programming.

The `PyPy` way seems the most reasonable, if it works you will gain a boost for all the simulations code.